# Two projects whit SMSSentReceiver with getResultCode first right second wrong

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

i have two projects on a phone , both of them have a BroadcastReceiver for SMS_SENT action , both of them called when a sms sent ,
i send an sms from second app when os receives SMS_SENT action  at the first os runs first app that installed and in it getResultCode has right value but after first app os runs second project reciver and in that getResultCode has wrong value

i expect in second project reciever getResultCode be Activity.RESULT_OK as them same as first project

first project manifest :

```
  <receiver
        android:name="ir.javan.ren.infra.sms.receiver.SMSSentReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

first project broadcast reciver :

```
public class SMSSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null
            &&intent.getExtras().containsKey(Constant.MESSAGE_LOG_KEY_2) ){


                    switch (getResultCode()){
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Utility.Toast(context,
                                hasSent, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        log.setSent(true);
                        MessageLogDAO.updateMessageLogSent(context,log);
                        break;
                    default :
                        Utility.Toast(context,
                                notSent, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    }
        }

    }


}
```

}

second project manifest :

```
 <receiver
        android:name="ir.javan.nazar_sanji.infra.sms.SMSSentReceiver"
         >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

second project receiver :

```
public class SMSSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null
            && intent.getExtras().containsKey(Constant.MESSAGE_LOG_KEY) ){

        switch (getResultCode()){
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Utility.Toast(context,
                    hasSent, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        default :
            Utility.Toast(context,
                    notSent, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Those broadcasts are apparently unordered, so you'll have to pass the result code to the second Receiver another way; perhaps by changing it's filter action, and broadcasting a new Intent from the first Receiver with that different action and the result code as an extra.

Comment: these projects are independent, i released them in app market , they cant't access each other

Comment: Huh? I didn't say anything about "accessing each other". I suggested changing the broadcast action in the second Receiver's entry in the manifest, and broadcasting with that action from the first.

Comment: Mike M. thanks, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

thanks  Mike M, i found it. one things i must do is change receiver action name. same name in first project action name and second project action name caused this problem . i just did  this in second project:

```
<action android:name="SMS_SENT_2" />
```